# How do I expose a attribute(setStagingMode) through JMX which is read only in WebLogic 14c

Tags: python, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst, weblogic14c

I am trying to change the stage mode of my application to 'nostage' via wlst Jython script. Currently the app is deployed in staging mode.
Here is my Jython Script:

```
import getopt, sys,traceback



server_name = 'myServer'
server_password = 'password'
server_username = 'username'
server_url = 'validURL'
App = 'AppName'


#           
connect(server_username, server_password, server_url)
edit()
startEdit()
cd('JMX/myDomain')
try:


        set('EditMBeanServerEnabled', 'true')
        cd('/AppDeployments/%s_%s' %(server_name,App))
        cmo.setStagingMode('nostage')               
except:

        traceback.print_exc()
save()
activate(block="true")
disconnect()
```

Error I am getting is:

> RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested attribute is not exposed through JMX: setStagingMode: Attribute is readonly. : com.bea:Name=myServer_AppName_,Type=AppDeployment:StagingMode

I want to change the staging mode from stage to nostage for my deployed application. What can I do to achieve this?